# Implications of protected variable starting with _ and CLSCompliant attribute

Tags: .net, cls-compliant

We have some C# code where there are protected variables that have been named with underscores

```
protected string _name;
public string Name
{
   get
   {
      return _name;
   }
   set
   {
      _name = value;
   }
}
```

This generates CLS compliance warnings, as CLS does not like underscores at the beginning.

What are the implications of marking the protected variable with [CLSCompliant(false)]? I don't even know what languages this is an issue with to test things. If _name is simply inaccessible this is fine for our purposes, but if it causes naming ambiguity it is not.

Comment: I meant to add - the intention is that there wouldn't be subclasses outside of our assembly.

Comment: If you want the field available within the assembly but not by inheritors, use `internal`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages don't support variables that start with an underscore. If a client using one of those languages wants to inherit from your class, he won't be able to access the `_name` field. What languages those are, I don't know.

From a design perspective, I'm wondering why you'd have a protected backing field when the public (and not virtual) property allows get and set directly. What's the point? In this case, giving inheritors access to the backing field provides no benefit and makes it impossible to change the implementation of the `Name` property.

Comment: I've been trying to argue for just changing the variables to private or automatic accessors for the same reasons but I've been meeting with resistance.

Comment: @Igaud: Just curious, but what rationale do the others give for their decision?

Comment: Their indecision, probably :)

Comment: The person who wrote this code feels that it somehow makes things easier for inheritance, I'm not exactly clear how.

Comment: To elaborate, he feels that sometimes the descendants of a class should be able to access to the field without having to go through anything "fancy" that may be added to the accessor in the future.

Comment: @lgaud: That design decision is horribly broken. By exposing that field, he limits what "fancy" things can be done in the future. For example, if the implementation is changed so that the `Name` property is lazily evaluated (based on a dirty flag, for example), then `_name` won't necessarily reflect the current value. If the implementation of `Name` is changed, then code breaks. Having that protected field there makes it difficult or impossible to change the implementation of `Name` without breaking existing code. And there's no compelling reason to have it in the first place.